# Multicast not working on hp 5820 switch

Tags: hp, multicast

I have a problem with getting multicast working on hp a5820 switch. I have 4 vlans vlan 1,20,30,40 with layerv3 vlans,  I enabled multicast routing and pim dm and igmp on each vlan. 
On the vlan 1 I can watch multicast streams on where the source is but not on other vlans. I only can watch them on other vlans if I open the stream with vlc player on vlan 1, when I exit vlc the stream stops on the other vlans. 
I set the configuration as per hp manual but still the problem,  what could be the problem?

Here is the config:

```
<HP>display current-configuration
#
 version 5.20.105, Release 1808P27
#
 sysname HP
#
 clock timezone z2 add 02:00:00
#
 irf mac-address persistent timer
 irf auto-update enable
 irf link-delay 1
 irf member 1 priority 10
#
 domain default enable system
#
 telnet server enable
#
 ip http enable
#
 multicast routing-enable
#
 password-recovery enable
#
acl number 3001
#
vlan 1
#
vlan 4
#
vlan 7
#
vlan 20
#
vlan 30
#
vlan 40
#
radius scheme system
 primary authentication 127.0.0.1 1645
 primary accounting 127.0.0.1 1646
 user-name-format without-domain
#
domain system
 access-limit disable
 state active
 idle-cut disable
 self-service-url disable
#
qos policy 1
#
dhcp server ip-pool basement1
 network 192.168.30.0 mask 255.255.254.0
 gateway-list 192.168.31.254
 dns-list 192.168.4.232 192.168.4.238 10.3.2.1 10.3.2.9
 nbns-list 192.168.4.232 10.3.2.9
 netbios-type h-node
 expired day 10
#
dhcp server ip-pool basement2
 network 192.168.20.0 mask 255.255.254.0
 gateway-list 192.168.21.254
 dns-list 192.168.4.232 192.168.4.238 10.3.2.1 10.3.2.9
 nbns-list 192.168.4.232 10.3.2.9
 netbios-type h-node
 expired day 10
#
dhcp server ip-pool news
 network 192.168.40.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 gateway-list 192.168.40.254
 dns-list 192.168.4.232 192.168.4.238
 nbns-list 10.3.2.9 192.168.4.232
 expired day 10
#
user-group system
 group-attribute allow-guest
#

interface NULL0
#
interface Vlan-interface1
 ip address 192.168.4.214 255.255.255.0
 igmp enable
 pim dm
#
interface Vlan-interface4
 ip address 192.168.50.254 255.255.255.0
 igmp enable
 pim dm
#
interface Vlan-interface7
 description Security Cameras Vlan
 ip address 192.168.2.254 255.255.255.0
#
interface Vlan-interface20
 description basement 2
 ip address 192.168.21.254 255.255.254.0
 igmp enable
 pim dm
#
interface Vlan-interface30
 description basement 1
 ip address 192.168.31.254 255.255.254.0
 igmp enable
 pim dm
#
interface Vlan-interface40
 ip address 192.168.40.254 255.255.255.0
 igmp enable
 pim dm
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/25
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 30
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/26
 port link-mode bridge
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/27
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 30
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/28
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 4
#
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/25
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 7
 broadcast-suppression 1
#
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/26
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 7
 broadcast-suppression 1
#
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/27
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 7
 broadcast-suppression 1
#
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/28
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 40
#
interface M-GigabitEthernet0/0/0
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 20
 flow-control
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 20
 flow-control
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 30
 flow-control
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/4
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 30
 flow-control
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/5
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 40
 flow-control
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/6
 port link-mode bridge
 port access vlan 40
 flow-control
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/7
 port link-mode bridge
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk permit vlan 1
 flow-control
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/8
 port link-mode bridge
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk permit vlan 1
 flow-control
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/9
 port link-mode bridge
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk permit vlan 1
 flow-control
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/10
 port link-mode bridge
 port link-type trunk
 port trunk permit vlan 1
 flow-control
#
rip 1
 version 1
 peer 192.168.4.245
 network 192.168.30.0
 network 192.168.20.0
 network 192.168.40.0
 network 192.168.21.0
 network 192.168.41.0
 network 192.168.31.0
 import-route static
#
pim
 auto-rp enable
#
 ip route-static 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.4.245
 ip route-static 10.3.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.4.245
#
irf-port 1/2
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/21 mode enhanced
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/22 mode enhanced
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/23 mode enhanced
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/24 mode enhanced
#
irf-port 2/1
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/21 mode enhanced
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/22 mode enhanced
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/23 mode enhanced
 port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/24 mode enhanced
#
```

Comment: Can you show your configuration?

Comment: I added them on the question but they are not formated well